# SecKeyGeneratePair public exponent

Tags: ios, macos, security-framework

Is it possible to change the default public exponent (e) when generating an RSA key pair using `SecKeyGeneratePair`?

I am aware 65537 is a good default, so this is just a question about whether it is technically possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not.

From https://github.com/unofficial-opensource-apple/Security, Security/sec/Security/SecRSAKey.c:

```
/* TODO: Add support for kSecPublicExponent parameter. */
static uint8_t e[] = { 0x01, 0x00, 0x01 }; // Default is 65537
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I had actually trawled the Security framework source before but somehow failed to spot it.